# Search engine to which I can apply my own filtering/reordering

Tags: open-source, web-apps, web-services, search-engine, google-search

I am looking for a website similar to Google Search, where I can apply some custom reordering and filtering to the search results.

For example I'd like to deprioritize sites with commerce focus (possibly using some third party API to categorize the sites).

I know Google has a custom search engine but it doesn't seem to be what I want - it's for defining a search engine on a *small subset of sites*. Whereas I want one that scours the whole Internet, or at least the part Google sees already.

I can program websites and could feasibly build something like this myself, but I'm wondering if there is something already out there.

Comment: So, you want a raw search API, right? You would get results from the API, filter/sort them like you want then display them on your website. Correct?

Comment: Perhaps look for the term meta crawler. There are sites already doing this, e.g. https://metager.de/ It's operated by an association. Perhaps they're willing to share some information on how they do it.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul exactly, and like I said, I could feasibly do this. But I'm wondering if an existing project exists.

Comment: Do you want results from Google, or would you be OK with results from another search engine such as DuckDuckGo or Bing?

Comment: Those are good too

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I think what I'm looking for is slightly different. It's less important to pull from multiple search engines than to reorder the results based on metadata

Comment: I think I understand your need better now, please check my edits. One thing: Why the open source tag? Do you need the search engine to be open source?

Comment: no, the search engine doesn't need to be open source, but the wrapper software  preferably is

Answer (score 1):

Anyway: that's my advice: Try to make your own SE: https://gitlab.metager3.de/. You may combine the work for your own with the possibility to earn some money: The Hackaton: see: suma-awards.de (german only)